# Thunderbird not updating certificate, keeps using old one and saying it's expired

Tags: email, thunderbird, ssl, letsencrypt

I have an email server where I have Let's Encrypt SSL certs, expiring every 3 months, and certbot automatically renews it. If I access the server through a website in the browser, the correct and newest SSL certificate is used, but thunderbird complains that the SSL certificate is not valid, by that it has expired.

The complaint is displayed through a dialog window, and if I click to view the certificate through this window, it shows an old certificate that has indeed expired. However, if I click the button "Get certificate", that button itself grays out, but nothing else happens. I tried right-clicking the name of the e-mail address (account) in thunderbird, and going to Settings -> Security and deleted all the certificates for the domain, but somehow still it has the old stored certificate stored.

My setup is dovecot + postfix.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Thunderbird does not access the mail using the same server as the browser does. The browser accesses a web server using HTTP/HTTPS while Thunderbird accesses a mail server using the IMAP/IMAPs or POP3/POP3s protocol for receiving mail and the SMTP protocol for sending. These are separate servers with separate configuration, which means that they need to be configured to use the appropriate certificates in the first place and that they must also be restarted when the certificates got renewed.

While it is impossible to say what your specific setup includes (EDIT: after an edit of the question it got clear that it is the setup I've described), a common setup is to use *dovecot* for receiving mail and *postfix* for sending. So you might try to look at these software and configurations on your (unknown) system and make sure that these get updated and restarted whenever the certificates change.

Comment: Thanks sir for the thoughts, I've now verified that both of these services indeed point to the same ssl files as the one for my https website, which are links pointing into the /etc/letsencrypt/archive, and then pointing to the renewed certificate files from a few days ago. I restarted the services for both and now Thunderbird sees a new certificate, with the new dates, but TB still won't accept it, saying that the cert is invalid! Is it possible the default certbot renew is too barebone to be accepted for mail?

Comment: @simernes: Thunderbird usually provides details of why it thinks the certificate is invalid. Typical problems if you reuse the same certificate for web and mail are that you might use different hostnames, i.e. www.example.com vs. mail.example.com. And if the certificate is only valid for the first it will fail when used for mail.

Comment: Thunderbird is telling me that the error stems from "Wrong site: The certificate belongs to a different site, which could mean that someone is trying to impersonate the site". Could that be because I have several domains on the same certificate?

Comment: @simernes:  That's exactly what I'm saying. You have a certificate which fits the name of your web server (i.e. www.example.com) but not your mail server (i.e. mail.example.com).

Answer (score 5):

Dovecot may need to be reloaded. I had exactly that case with Postfix+Dovecot+certbot.  Certbot was showing the certificate is already renewed, but still the server was using expired certificate.  I was able to see that by testing with openssl (Ubuntu):

```
openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:993 -quiet
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mydomain.com
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Dec  5 15:42:11 2020 GMT
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mydomain.com
notAfter=Dec  5 15:42:11 2020 GMT
verify return:1
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE  AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.
^C
```

Reload Dovecot:

```
sudo service dovecot reload
```

That was enough to fix it in my case.
Still it may be worth checking whether reboot is requested for the server:

```
ls -l /var/run/reboot-required
```

Comment: Same here, thunderbird couldn't see the new issued certificate after I added a new domain name, checking for the certificate date I figured the old one was still used, restarting dovecot solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've observed a similar issue when connecting to an letsencrypt-enabled SMTP server (postfix) using the submission port 587 with STARTTLS.
After an hour of debugging I found out that Thunderbird leveraged TLS Session Resumption and therefore did not perform a full TLS handshake, hence the new certificate had not been sent by the server.
I'm not sure yet whether this is a bug in TB or a misconfiguration on server side - as for now I've set session expiration time to 0s on server side (thus actually disabling server side session caching) and restarted postfix, which instantly solved the issue.

Based on that configuration, TLS sessions should now be stored client side in respective session tickets. However, I've not found out yet *where* these are stored and how to flush the cache. Flushing the cache should be the absolute key to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced this issue twice.

I run a CentOS (Stream) with postfix, dovecot, amavisd, mysql, clamd, spamassassin, selinux, opendkim, opendmarc and letsencrypt / certbot.

I have 3 email domains and a number of web domains so I have separate certificates for each domain and server that certbot renews automatically just fine.

However, because I am using sni_maps (check postifx), when the certificate gets replaced by certbot, while postfix may restart / reload, the sni_map.db file needs to be recreated with postmap -F otherwise the certificate will not be updated.

Comment: So, how do you update the certificate? You need to answer the question, not simply discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Robert Haller [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1656009/1815416) I managed to fix this. If anyone is stuck on this issue with Thunderbird not seeing the new and valid certificates and have the same setup with dovecot postfix and certbot, with multiple mail servers on their VM, you probably use sni.map which need to be remapped after certificate update.
So the solution for me was:

```
postmap -F hash:/etc/postfix/sni.map
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).